# React Router cancel loader

Tags: react-router

I'm throwing an error in my loaders when `response.status.ok` of `fetch` is false. Error component is then loaded.

But my server sometimes returns 429 status code (too many requests) upon which I don't want to load an error component but instead simply do nothing, or maybe display some message but certainly without reloading the already loaded component, or redirecting, etc.
How can that be implemented?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-hooks-yuucsp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Check the error status code in the loader? Can you [edit] to share a [mcve] of the relevant code since it's rather difficult to address issues in code we can't see?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I can check the status code but what to do next? What to return from loader so as to not change the already loader component?

Comment: You can return anything you like from a loader function. Is the routed component for the route with a loader function also relevant [mcve] material here?

Comment: @DrewReese I've added an example of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the response status code specifically for a 429 status and return any *defined* value back to the UI. I think the important detail here that you should return *something* instead of `undefined`. `null` appears to work and not throw any extraneous errors

```js
function loader() {
  let response = imitateFetch();
  console.log(response);

  if (response.status === 429) {
    console.log(429);
    return null; // <-- return null
  }

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw "loader error";
  }
  return {};
}
```

but you can return anything you like, for example, change the response status to 200.

```js
function loader() {
  let response = imitateFetch();
  console.log(response);

  if (response.status === 429) {
    console.log(429);
    response.status = 200;
    response.ok = true;
    return response;
  }

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw "loader error";
  }
  return {};
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-cancel-loader]

It's really up to your app's, or code's, specific use case what it returns and how the UI handles it.